# Mule FTP download default delete off

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Using mule ftp:inbound-endpoint how to

- Use filename filter to look for file "*CurrentMonth(MMM)*.csv" and download a copy on a local server directory.
- Once download is done switch off the default delete functionality so as not to make any changes on the ftp site.

Below is flow config

`<flow name="ftpFlow1">
 <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="apca.com.au" port="21" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP"/>
</flow>`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:objectstore="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/current/mule-objectstore.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <objectstore:config name="ObjectStore__Connector" partition="testObjec" doc:name="ObjectStore: Connector"/>
    <file:endpoint path="inp_path" moveToPattern="doloaded_file_name" moveToDirectory="local_directory_to_download" name="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="CurrentMonth(MMM).csv" caseSensitive="true"/>
    </file:endpoint>
    <flow name="testFlow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <file:outbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" ref="File" doc:name="File"/>
        </poll>
    </flow>

 
</mule>
```